# Can't use getAsset() in a Dialog class

Tags: android

```
public class Class_UniversityDialog extends Dialog {

public Class_UniversityDialog(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.layout_university_info);

    Typeface face = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "tahoma.ttf");
    //To Layout Topic persian
    TextView txt_Title = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.lbl_LayoutTopic);
    txt_Title.setTypeface(face);
    String newText = (String) txt_Title.getText().toString();
    txt_Title.setText(PersianReshape.reshape(newText));
}
```

}

In my code eclipse says that getAssets() : " The method getAssets() is undefined for the type Class_UniversityDialog"

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to use context.getAssets(). before you use it define context and initialize it.

```
public class Class_UniversityDialog extends Dialog {
Context context;

public Class_UniversityDialog(Context context) {
super(context);
this.context = context;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Use

```
getContext().getAssets()
```

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Dialog.html#getContext()

Comment: thanks, this also solved my problem but I prefer the Marcin S. solution

Answer (score 0):

```
Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),"fonts/verdana.ttf");
textfield.setTypeface(tf,Typeface.BOLD);
```

> You can use like that this one has your prblem solved